# VBA Array Declaration Using a Variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it true that you cannot declare a visual basic array of a size provided by a variable? This seems like a reasonable requirement for any scripting language, and so I expect I am doing something wrong.

In the following example...

```
Sub TestRoutine()
    Dim tVar As Integer: tVar = 5
    Dim tArr(tVar) As String
    tArr(3) = "SUCCESS"
    MsgBox tArr(3)
End Sub
```

... the execution fails with the message `Compile error: Constant expression required`

I use a dynamic array instead, but this seems like an ugly workaround. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is right. The closest you can get is - as the compiler suggests - to use a constant:

```
Sub TestRoutine()
    Const tVar      As Integer = 5
    Dim tArr(tVar)  As String        
    tArr(3) = "SUCCESS"
    MsgBox tArr(3)
End Sub
```

Another option which is handy, say, when using Split or Array, is to use a Variant:

```
Sub TestRoutine()
    Dim vArr  As Variant
    vArr = Array("0", "1", "2", "Yet a SUCCESS")
    MsgBox vArr(3)    
End Sub
```